# How to make array of object with limmited values

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, reduce

Sorry, in advance if  the title is unclear, but it's hard to describe it in a words.

What I have:

```
const obj = {
 a: 5,
 b: 3,
 c: 0,
 d: 9
}
```

What I want to have:

```
const arr = [[a, 5] ,[b, 3]]
```

Basically, I try to write a function that return me array of entries, but it has too meet requirements:

- don't want objects when values is **equal to 0**
- sum of values must be **less than 10**

First point is easy for me and I can do it by

```
Object.entries(obj).filter(([k, v])=> v !== 0)
```

but I can't handle with the second one.

May I use `reduce` here?

Comment: It's slightly unclear: what should happen if the sum is larger than 10?

Comment: why not `[['d', 9]]`?

Comment: What if you have `f: 4` - should that also possibly produce `[["a", 5], ["f", 4]]` or `[["b", 3], ["f", 4]]`? And how would you choose which output is correct?

Comment: @kikon you keep including items until the sum of the values is 10 or higher.

Comment: Also, what is the expected output for `{ a: 5, b: 9, c: 0, d: 3 }` - it is `[["a", 5], ["d", 3]]` or `[["a", 5]]`?

Comment: what if you have `e: 1`? should it add to the result set?

Comment: No, I want to have to adding values in order starting from a. 
So if {a: 0, b: 0, c: 8, d: 0, e: 1, f: 5} I expect [[ c, 8], [e, 1]]. If { a: 12, b: 3} I expect []

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to store the sum

```
Object.entries(obj).filter((() => {
  let sum = 0;
  return ([k, v]) => { sum += v; return v !== 0 && sum < 10; }; 
})());
```

Examples:

```js
function convert(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj).filter((() => {
    let sum = 0;
    return ([k, v]) => { sum += v; return v !== 0 && sum < 10; }; 
  })());
}

const obj = { a: 5, b: 3, c: 0, d: 9 };
const arr = convert(obj);
console.log(arr);

const obj2 = { a: 0, b: 0, c: 8, d: 0, e: 1, f: 5 };
const arr2 = convert(obj2);
console.log(arr2);

const obj3 = { a: 12 };
const arr3 = convert(obj3);
console.log(arr3);
```

Answer (score 0):

[@jabaa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70068786) is great and you should accept it.

Just to confirm your intuition, you could have used `reduce`, but it would get rather complicated:

```js
const obj = {
 a: 5,
 b: 3,
 c: 0,
 d: 9
}

const result = Object.entries(obj).reduce(
  (o, newPair) => {
     o.sum += newPair[1];
     newPair[1] !== 0 && o.sum < 10 && o.pairs.push(newPair);
     return o;
  },
  {
     sum: 0,
     pairs: []
  }
).pairs;

console.log(result)
```

Comment: indeed, definitely!